# Andorid - Gradle - Execution Failed For Task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex' Error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I'm trying to do a build clean on my Android project and when I do I end up with the error:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex.' > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl$1.class
BUILD FAILED

Here is a current copy of my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.engineering"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/butterknife-5.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/com.google.guava_1.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/com.springsource.org.junit-4.10.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/opencsv-3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.45.jar')
    compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.16.jar')
    compile files('libs/icepick-2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar')
}
```

I have tried this with the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.engineering"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/butterknife-5.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/com.google.guava_1.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/com.springsource.org.junit-4.10.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/opencsv-3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.6.jar') { 
        exclude group: 'BaseDoaImpl'
    }
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.45.jar')
    compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.16.jar')
    compile files('libs/icepick-2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar')
}
```

When I do I get the following error: "Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'
Possible causes:
- The project "project name" may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
- The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

Here is a current copy of my Gradle Wrapper File:

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

How can I fix this issue?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you use `compile ('libs/ormlite-android-4.6.jar') { exclude group: 'BaseDoaImpl' }`?

Comment: When I do use compile ('libs/ormlite-android-4.6.jar') { exclude group: 'BaseDoaImpl' } I get the following error: "Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()' Possible causes: - The project "project name" may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. - The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

Comment: When I remove { exclude group: 'BaseDoaImpl' } from the code I get the following error: Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex.' > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl$1.class BUILD FAILED

Comment: `ormlite-core` should be dependency of `ormlite`, its declaration might be redundant. Try to remove `ormlite-core` from dependencies

Comment: I tried that and I end up with some issues with my code. I need to include both of these JAR files in the project.